# Ada. How to instance up to 1000 generic packages in a ravenscar real time profile

Tags: generics, ada

I have a generic package with a buffer functionality encapsulated using Ravenscar pragma profile.

This buffer also has protected procedures and entries for multitasking.

I need to instantiate several of these packages. The code is now working in this way:

> package buffer1 is new buffer(configuration_1);
>
> package buffer2 is new buffer(configuration_2);
>
> .....
>
> package buffer1000 is new buffer(configuration_1000);

The problem is that I will maybe need up to 500 or 1000 independent buffer packages, so I'm trying to think of another way to instantiate these generic packages and then fill 500 or 1000 lines of these instances.

To make things more difficult, Ravenscar pragma profile obligates me to define that everything is posible in compilation time.

I was looking to do something like a "constrained generics package array" but I don't know how to manage this situation in this language.

Does anybody knows a better approach to his problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How do the configurations vary?

Comment: in the worst case, configuration could be different for every buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Gnat.Bounded_Buffers` on the assumption you are using the GNAT compiler. It is a threadsafe generic buffer implementation that works quite well. I used to have a coworker that loved writing his own implementations, but the abstractions are often very limiting and rather brittle. This `Gnat.Bounded_Buffers` should work for you. If you need help with implementing it let me know.